# How do I reset a UIPickerView when it is associated with a TextField's inputView?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have a UITextField that has its inputView set equal to a UIPickerView

```
let thePicker = UIPickerView()
txtCategory.inputView = thePicker
thePicker.delegate = self
```

I have these functions for the picker

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return categoryList.count
}

func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return categoryList[row]
}

func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    txtCategory.text = categoryList[row]
}
```

How would I go about setting to picker back to index of 0 after a button is pressed? I think this code will do the job `myPicker.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: false)`, I just don't know what my picker control is named since I set the textfield's input view equal to the picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once solution would be to implement the `func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)` delegate method. And then see if the text field's `inputView` is a picker view. If so, reset the picker view as needed.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if let picker = textField.inputView as? UIPickerView {
        picker.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
    }
}
```

If you have multiple text fields that use a picker view and you only want to reset the picker for some of the text fields, then add a check to see if `textField` is one of the ones you need to handle.

Comment: Worked like a charm!